# Is the relation "$A$ is r.e. (recursively enumerable) relative to $B$" transitive?

Tags: logic, computability

I wonder if $A$ r.e. (recursively enumerable) relative to $B$ is transitive. Here I say relative to means $A$ is the domain of some partial function that is recursive in B. Intuitively, I think it is not transitive but I simply can not find a proper counter-example...

Please offer some help, thank you.

Comment: A counterexample does exist indeed. In fact, you can even take $C$ to be any recursive set, i.e. $B$ is r.e., $A$ is r.e. (even recursive) relative to $B$ but not r.e. Can you think of a counterexample now?

Comment: Can you be more specific? You mean A is not r.e. but r.e. relative to B, and B is r.e. and C is recursive set, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should have said that $B$ is r.e. but not co-r.e., but this basically gives away the solution (for what $A$ should be).

Comment: So, can the answer be, let A be {turing machine not halting on i} and B be {turing machines halting on i} and then at last C can be anything because B itself is r.e.

Comment: You need to make "Turing machine not halting on $i$" more rigorous, but that's the idea. 
And you also can't take $C$ to be anything, just play it safe (in case $A$ becomes r.e. relative to $C$). Other than that, you've got it.

Comment: Thanks, sure, for C I just want to say as long as C won't help A, it's fine, basically let C be  a quite recursive set will do.